# Why gulp-purgecss whitelist is not working

Tags: css, sass, gulp, css-purge

Hello I am using Gulp for compiling and Tailwind as framework.
I would like to use Purgecss, it is working but it ignores my whitelist, some help?

Here the code example:

```
function css() {
    const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
    return gulp.src('./src/assets/css/main.css')
    .pipe(postcss([
      require('precss'),
      tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
      require('autoprefixer')
    ]))
    .pipe(purgecss({
      content: ['./public/*.html'],
      whitelist: ['px-4'],
      whitelistPatterns: [/^bg-/, /^text-/],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting names have been renamed, use new names (**safelist**) and approach

[purgecss safelist](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html)

```
    const purgecss = new Purgecss({
    content: [], // content
    css: [], // css
    safelist: {
      standard: [/red$/],
      deep: [/blue$/],
      greedy: [/yellow$/]
    }
})
```

Glad if it helped you ;)